# MultiPolgyon search on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I can't seem to figure this out and would appreciate any and all help. 
I am using Node.js to make a query to MongoDB using the MultiPolygon filter. I am connecting to the native driver rather than using Mongoose because it doesn't seem like Mongoose supports MultiPolygon (absent in docs).

I receive a malformed query error though

```
GatheredListings.collection.find({
            $and: [ 
                { 'rentAmount': { $gte: filterParameters.minPrice } }, 
                { 'rentAmount': { $lte: filterParameters.maxPrice } }, 
                { 'availabilityDate': { $gte: filterParameters.date } },
                { 'propertyType': filterParameters.propertyType },
                { 'bedrooms': filterParameters.bedrooms },
                { 'location': {
                   $geoWithin: {
                      $geometry: {
                         type : "MultiPolygon" ,
                         coordinates: [ 
                            geoArrayCollection
                        ] 
                      }
                   }} 
                }
            ]
         }).toArray(function(err, properties) {

                if (err || !properties)
                {
                    console.log('err ' + err);
                    callback("No properties found", null);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Number of properties retrieved: ' + properties.length);
                    callback(null, properties);
                }
         });`
```

The error is : 
`err MongoError: Malformed geo query: { $geoWithin: { $geometry: { type:    "MultiPolygon", coordinates: [ [ [ [ 43.77307711737606, -79.53517913818359 ], [ 43.79191518340848, -79.4476318359375 ], [ 43.75559702541283, -79.43887710571289 ], [ 43.7501411993079, -79.46514129638672 ], [ 43.7541091221655, -79.46943283081055 ], [ 43.75547303488856, -79.47406768798828 ], [ 43.75510106177428, -79.47715759277344 ], [ 43.75435710860915, -79.48093414306641 ], [ 43.75200119590339, -79.48282241821289 ], [ 43.74592499302, -79.48316574096678 ], [ 43.74282465186857, -79.49621200561523 ], [ 43.7404682852067, -79.49604034423828 ], [ 43.73873195568971, -79.49295043945312 ], [ 43.73525914559611, -79.49501037597655 ], [ 43.73538317799622, -79.50410842895508 ], [ 43.73290248118248, -79.51148986816406 ], [ 43.73947610307701, -79.51320648193359 ], [ 43.73649945803657, -79.52642440795898 ], [ 43.77307711737606, -79.53517913818359 ] ], [ [ 43.79203909839882, -79.4476318359375 ], [ 43.80380985089954, -79.39647674560547 ], [ 43.76334592336985, -79.38712120056152 ], [ 43.76179622406369, -79.39501762390137 ], [ 43.73600333614323, -79.43381309509277 ], [ 43.79203909839882, -79.4476318359375 ] ] ] ] } } }

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this helps troubleshoot the issue further, but I am connecting to MongoLabs and connecting to node-mongodb-native using Mongoose (from what I understand .collection bypasses Mongoose and goes straight to the node-mongodb-native.

Answer (score 0):

The MultiPolygon wasn't formatted correctly. You wanted this:

```
{
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                [
                    43.77307711737606,
                    -79.5351791381836
                ],
                [
                    43.79191518340848,
                    -79.4476318359375
                ],
                [
                    43.75559702541283,
                    -79.43887710571289
                ],
                [
                    43.7501411993079,
                    -79.46514129638672
                ],
                [
                    43.7541091221655,
                    -79.46943283081055
                ],
                [
                    43.75547303488856,
                    -79.47406768798828
                ],
                [
                    43.75510106177428,
                    -79.47715759277344
                ],
                [
                    43.75435710860915,
                    -79.4809341430664
                ],
                [
                    43.75200119590339,
                    -79.48282241821289
                ],
                [
                    43.74592499302,
                    -79.48316574096678
                ],
                [
                    43.74282465186857,
                    -79.49621200561523
                ],
                [
                    43.7404682852067,
                    -79.49604034423828
                ],
                [
                    43.73873195568971,
                    -79.49295043945312
                ],
                [
                    43.73525914559611,
                    -79.49501037597655
                ],
                [
                    43.73538317799622,
                    -79.50410842895508
                ],
                [
                    43.73290248118248,
                    -79.51148986816406
                ],
                [
                    43.73947610307701,
                    -79.5132064819336
                ],
                [
                    43.73649945803657,
                    -79.52642440795898
                ],
                [
                    43.77307711737606,
                    -79.5351791381836
                ]
            ]
        ],  // <--- missing this
        [   // <--- missing this
            [
                [
                    43.79203909839882,
                    -79.4476318359375
                ],
                [
                    43.80380985089954,
                    -79.39647674560547
                ],
                [
                    43.76334592336985,
                    -79.38712120056152
                ],
                [
                    43.76179622406369,
                    -79.39501762390137
                ],
                [
                    43.73600333614323,
                    -79.43381309509277
                ],
                [
                    43.79203909839882,
                    -79.4476318359375
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

but you were missing a layer of closing and opening of arrays that I have highlighted. The structures are big and nested so it's hard to eyeball what is going on; I'd suggest using tools like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) and [geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/) to contrast my corrected structure with your previous structure. It's the only way I was able to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks, good catch re: formatting, but that still doesn't solve the issue. I have actually tried a variety of various formatting options. The above doesn't work either :(

Comment: Can you post the full query that you're doing? What version of MongoDB are you using? In MongoDB 2.6.7, if I cut and paste my corrected structure into a `$geoWithin`, it works fine.